# Condense several columns read with Spark CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have data like the following in a CSV file:

```
ColumnA,1,2,3,2,1
"YYY",242,34234,232,322,432
"ZZZ",16,435,363,3453,3434
```

I want to read it with https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

I would like to read this into a DataFrame and condense all the columns except the first one into a `Seq`.

So I would like to obtain something like this from it:

```
MyCaseClass("YYY", Seq(242,34234,232,322,432))
MyCaseClass("ZZZ", Seq(16,435,363,3453,3434))
```

I'm not sure how to obtain that.

I tried reading like this, where url is the location of the file:

```
val rawData = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(url)
```

Then, I am mapping it into the values that I want.

The problem is that I get the error:

```
The header contains a duplicate entry: '1'
```

So how can I condense all the fields except the first into a `Seq` using `spark-csv`?

**EDIT**

I can not change the format of the input.

Comment: In your input CSV file you have two columns named `1`, which is not allowed in Spark's DataFrames since they require distinct names for their columns. You should fix that first and try to implement your thing then.

Answer (score -1):

you can do by mapping over row . And also as Pawel's comment duplicate column name is not allowed. So, you can do like :

```
val dataFrame = yourCSV_DataFrame

dataFrame.map{row =>
Row(row(0), Seq(row(1), row(2), row(3) ...))
}
```

Comment: I can't change the format of the input. I want to change the reading to process to accommodate this format.